# validateAssociated overwriting associated model's errors, possible bug?

Tags: cakephp

I'm running with cakephp version 2.0.2 and was scratching my head as to why a form submission that submits data to an association of models was not revealing error messages for the associations.

I've been digging into the Model class to diagnose further. I found that if the primary model for the form had its own validation errors, then no validation errors for any associations would ever be revealed in the returned:

```
$this->validationErrors
```

But I think I found the smoking gun. In the Model.php's `validateAssociated` method, you'll see this:

```
$this->validationErrors = $validationErrors;
if (isset($validationErrors[$this->alias])) {
    $this->validationErrors = $validationErrors[$this->alias];
}
```

The first line sets `$this->validationErrors` to contain all built up errors across all associations. But if `$validationErrors` contains errors for the key of `$this->alias` which is the primary model name, then as you can see, `$this->validationErrors` gets overwritten to just those errors.

So this begs the question.... why? I'm so certain this is a bug I want to modify my Model.php and I think it'll work. But I wanted to get this in front of others in case I'm doing something really stupid here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. Its like that for BC. I know, it sucks. It should be a bug. The way I work around it is by re-formatting validation errors.

```
// AppModel.php

public function formatValidationErrors($models) {
    foreach($models as $model => $assoc) {
        if (is_numeric($model)) {
            $model = $assoc;
            $assoc = null;
        }
        $this->validationErrors[$model] = $this->{$model}->validationErrors;
        if ($assoc) {
            $this->{$model}->formatValidationErrors($assoc);
        }
    }
}
```

I call that if validation fails, and pass an array like you would do to contain. You can use that if you don't want to modify the core.